# Mapping Angular input fields to Go struct with array using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, go, restangular

I have a Go struct:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name   string   `json:"fooName"`
    Things []string `json:"things"`
}
```

I have an Angular html page:

```
<input type="text" name="fooName" ng-model="foo.fooName"/>

<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <input ng-model="foo.things" type="text" name="thing-{{$index}}"/>
</div>
```

In the Angular controller I have:

```
$scope.save= function(){
    Restangular
        .all('foos/new')
        .post($scope.foo).then(function(foo) {
            $location.path('/admin/fooManagement');
        });
};
```

The rest service call calls:

```
func CreateFoo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    var f Foo
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    dec.Decode(&f)
    log.Println("**** CreateFoo.... ")
    log.Println(&d)
}
```

Foo's name comes through, but I cannot get the "Things" array populated with the input values.
I'm trying to figure out how to get the post service call to populate the array.

Comment: try `name="thing[{{$index}}]"`

Comment: That helped, but how do i get multiple inputs working in the repeat, for if they all have the same ng-model value, "foo.things", all inputs will have the same value...i want to have a few inputs that have different values that then populate the array?

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced in AngularJS, but I do know Javascript and Go pretty well:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <input type="text" ng-value="foo.things[$index]" name="thing[{{$index}}]"/>
</div>
```

Assuming that `foo.things` and `things` are not the same array and that both are in scope.

With the `ng-value` directive, we're binding this input's value to `foo.things`' element at index `$index`.

And the `name` attribute follows Restangular's (undocumented) array-notation.

Comment: Don't copy-paste the code and say it doesn't work. What exactly doesn't work? What have you tried? What error do you see?

Comment: Why did you assume I copied and pasted code, as opposed to adapting your solution to my situation? No explicit error, the array "things" is not being populated with the solution. I did have to use ng-value="foo.things[{{$index}}], but that did not solve the problem. I do not know why it did not work, just as I do not know why my attempt did not work. So, I'm still trying to find the right combo of ng-value and name and such, and I've tried too many combos to list (so I'm hoping for some other variant to try, and I'm hopeful that what you introduced, ng-value, is a step in the right direction:)